# Exporting data from overpass turbo

Tags: openstreetmap

[image]

I'm working with osm data. I wanted to download all the waysin a florida county. I tested my query in overpass turbo and it produced about 20mb of data. there is a warning saying this is probably to much for my browser. I tried to export the data  but got only a few lines at the beginning.

Is there a better way to export this data from open street map?